# Analysis to identify groups of occupations with similar skill demand from job postings?

Tags: r, clustering

Was told to post this here so hope it's the right place!

I am using a very large dataset of job postings, which for each posting has a unique posting ID, the job posting occupation, and a row for each skill requested in each job posting.

The dataset looks a bit like this:

| posting_id | occ_code | occname | skillname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | data scientist | analysis |
| 1 | 1 | data scientist | python |
| 2 | 2 | lecturer | teaching |
| 2 | 2 | lecturer | economics |
| 3 | 3 | biologist | research |
| 3 | 3 | biologist | biology |
| 4 | 1 | data scientist | research |
| 4 | 1 | data scientist | R |

I'd like to perform analysis (in R) to identify "related" occupations by how similar their overall skill demand is in job postings. E.g. using a sample of 1000 postings for data scientists and 1000 for financial analysts, if many of the postings requested the same skills they could be considered closely related occupations.

There are hundreds of different occupations in the dataset, but out of those I'm interested in identifying occupations with similar kind of "skill profile" to 25 specific occupations I have selected.

Haven't done anything like this before so I'm struggling to come up with what type of analysis would be appropriate to achieve this. Would greatly appreciate any advice!

Comment: There is a working paper that uses BERT to do [that.](https://hai.stanford.edu/news/words-matter-text-online-job-postings-can-predict-salaries)

Comment: @dimitriy This is a promotional piece that Stanford wrote for one of its scientist. As universities do nowadays.
The link "Indeed, using machine learning, Bana recently showed that ..." doesn't even open anymore.
Since the only thing that seems to have been shown about these large language models is that they are biased against minorities of various kinds, it might be a good idea to not promote this yourself?

Comment: Here is [the link to the paper itself](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/573f69a2cf80a1adb090ba64/t/63b7aaefd09bf6373f4c7e61/1672981234385/work2vec_salaries.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of skill names like words, job postings like sentences, and occupations like books.

Two books are similar if they use a lot of the same words, perhaps taking into account their frequency.  Similarly, two occupations are similar if the job postings for those occupations mention the same skills.

Roughly, I would:

- Count how many times a skill is mentioned in an occupation.  You could merge all the postings together here.
- Create a occupation-skill matrix.  Rows are occupations, skills are columns, and the entry in position i,j is the count of times skill j is mentioned for occupation i.
- Perform any method of similarity you like.  I think transfgorming the counts using TF-IDF and then doing something as simple as a cosine similarity would work perfectly fine.

There is no "right" approach here because "similar" is not well defined.  So you have to make some choices about how to represent the skills within occupations, and some decisions about how to define "similar" in that representation.  I've mentioned but one way, but you could for example just do 1s and 0s for if the skill is mentioned in any of the job postings for that occupation and then compute a Jaccard index.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply and I really like the idea. I wasn't familiar with TF-IDF and it looks good - one issue though is that because there are so many job postings (millions), many of the skills are mentioned in every occupation's job postings at least once. From my (limited) understanding of TF-IDF, does this mean I can't use it? It seems like even if a skill is mentioned 10,000 times in postings for one occupation and one single time in every other occupation, this would ruin it due to how the IDF calculation works.

Comment: @Dandae No this should be fine.  TF-IDF will down weight the skill if it appears in a lot of postings (that is, lots of postings for different roles).  This is the IDF part of TFIDF.

Comment: If they just appeared in lots of postings it would be fine, but due to the high number of postings in the dataset, for many of the skills they appear in at least one posting for every occupation, which makes the IDF value 0 (and therefore TF-IDF value also 0) for a large proportion of the skills.

Comment: Just to update on this, I've decided to use the IDF formula here: https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html

to ensure the calculate IDF > 0